# How to (robustly) capture the contents of nested lists?

Tags: lists

**How come it's so tricky to get a robust way to capture the contents of nested lists ?**

Before trying to understand the `itemize` or `enumerate` environments, I checked plain TeX definition of `\item` the`TeXbook`. I understand that `\item` is a function defined as

"Plain TEX uses hanging indentation in its ' `\item` macro, which produces a paragraph in which every line has the same indentation as a normal `\indent`. Furthermore, `\item` takes a parameter that is placed into the position of the indentation on the first line. Another macro called `\itemitem` does the same thing but with double indentation.
"

No mandatory argument but an optional argument as in `\item[$\bullet$]` in a list.

It seems difficult though to get the content of the text after `\item` in lists.

It would actually be easier for `TeX` to have `\item{bla bla bla}` (between braces) to retrieve this content. This is what's done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275502/add-list-items-to-table-of-contents) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142330/redefine-item-command-to-not-typeset-some-items/142344#142344) for **non nested** lists.

Other answers led to external languages. In python for instance, [TeXsoup](https://pypi.org/project/TexSoup/)  aims at organizing all the content of a .tex file into a dataframe and as such, handle this question.

I'd like to stay inside TeX.

`beamer` compatibility with `\item<i->` as an option would be great...

**Example of application** : easily turn a boring list into a mindmap

**NB :** This question arose during this discussion in another [nice TeX Community](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1818) regarding how to create an environment that would render a nested list into a mindmap.

[image]
[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\definecolor{myuniversity}{RGB}{36, 0, 132} 

%--------------------
% GrowCycle
% Till level 5
%--------------------
\makeatletter
\newif\ifmmap@debug
\mmap@debugfalse
\newcommand{\mmap@debug@message}[1]{\ifmmap@debug
    \typeout{#1}%
    \fi}
\def\tikz@mmap@store@aux#1#2{%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\xdef\noexpand\csname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\string\endcsname{#2}}}%
\def\tikz@mmap@get@from@aux#1#2{%
\ifcsname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\endcsname
\edef#2{\csname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\endcsname}%
\else
\edef#2{0}%
\fi
}   
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{MMapNodesAtLevel}{1}{%
\tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-\@roman{#1}}{\pgfmathresult}}
\newcount\tikzcountchildi
\newcount\tikzcountchildii
\newcount\tikzcountchildiii
\newcount\tikzcountchildiv
\newcount\tikzcountchildv
\newcount\tikzcountchildvi
\tikzcountchildi=0
\tikzcountchildii=0
\tikzcountchildiii=0
\tikzcountchildiv=0
\tikzcountchildv=0
\tikzcountchildvi=0
\tikzset{Julien growth/.style={%
    growth function=\tikz@grow@Julien,
    mmap/initialize counts,
    /tikz/execute at end scope={%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-i}{\the\tikzcountchildi}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-ii}{\the\tikzcountchildii}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-iii}{\the\tikzcountchildiii}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-iv}{\the\tikzcountchildiv}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-v}{\the\tikzcountchildv}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-vi}{\the\tikzcountchildvi}%
    }},
    mmap/.cd,
    initialize counts/.code={\global\tikzcountchildi=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildii=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildiii=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildiv=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildv=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildvi=0%
    }
}


\def\tikz@grow@Julien{%
    \pgftransformreset% 
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall xshift}}%
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall yshift}}}%
    \ifcase\tikztreelevel 
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildi}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildi by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildii}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildii by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildiii}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildiii by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildiv}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildiv by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildv}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildv by1\relax%
    \fi
    \mmap@debug@message{level=\the\tikztreelevel,%
        \the\tikzcountchildi,\the\tikzcountchildii,\the\tikzcountchildiii,
        rotation=\pgfutil@tempb,sibling angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}}%
    \pgftransformrotate{\pgfutil@tempb}%
    \pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
}
\makeatother
                
                
\tikzset{%
mmap/.cd,
    name/.initial=undef,
    overall rotation/.initial   = 0,
    overall xshift/.initial     = 0pt,
    overall yshift/.initial     = 0pt,
    sign/.initial               = 1,                
    child weight/.initial       = 0.5,      
    rotation/.initial           = 0.5,
    shape angle/.initial        = 180,      
    distance to 1/.initial      = 4.5cm,        
    distance to 2/.initial      = 7.5cm,        
    distance to 3/.initial      = 10cm,     
    distance to 4/.initial      = 12cm,     
    distance to 5/.initial      = 14cm,     
    offset level 3/.initial     = 0,        
/tikz/.cd,
    offset angle/.initial=0, 
    Xshift/.style={xshift=#1,mmap/overall xshift=#1},
    Yshift/.style={yshift=#1,mmap/overall yshift=#1},
%    branch color/.style={
%        concept color=#1!80,
%        ball color=#1!50,
%        every child/.append style={concept color=#1!50},
%    },
}


%----------------------------------------------
% Style of the mindmap
%----------------------------------------------
\tikzset{mymmstyle/.style 2 args={
    text width=1.5cm,
    align=flush center,
    mindmap,
    Julien growth,
    mmap/overall rotation=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/rotation},
    mmap/sign   = 1,
    mmap/name   = semicirc, %<- you need unique names if you want to use several mindmaps
    every node/.style={
        concept,
        circular drop shadow, 
        execute at begin node=\hskip0pt,
        text=#2,
    },  
    node font=\sffamily,
    nodes={concept},
    concept color=#1,
    root concept/.append style={
        ball color=#1, 
        line width=1.5ex,
        text=#2,
        font=\LARGE\bfseries\scshape,
        minimum size=3.25cm, 
        text width=3.25cm
    },                   
    level 1/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 1},%
        font=\large,%
        minimum size=2.5cm,%
        text width=2.0cm, 
        fill= #1!70,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(1)-1),1)}
    },
    level 2/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 2},%
        font=\normalsize,%
        minimum size=1.5cm,%
        text width=1.5cm, 
        fill= #1!50,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(2)-1),1)}
    },
    level 3/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 3},
        font=\normalsize,
        minimum size=1.5cm,
        text width=1.5cm, 
        fill= #1!30,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(3)-1),1)},
        offset angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/offset level 3}
    },
    level 4/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 4},
        font=\normalsize,
        minimum size=1cm,
        text width=1cm, 
        fill= #1!30,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(4)-1),1)},
        offset angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/offset level 4}
    },
}
}


%\newcommand{\MyMindMap}[2][mymmstyle={blue}{white}]{
%\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]    
%%  \begin{scope}[#1]   
%%  \input{#2}
%{#2}
%%  \end{scope}
%\end{tikzpicture}
%}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Audience catching mindmap}

    
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[mymmstyle={orange}{orange!50!black}]
                
                \node[root concept] {Root} 
                child {node {level 1}
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}              
                    }
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                    }
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                    }
                }
                child {node {level 1}
                    child {node {level 2}}
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}      
                    }
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}      
                    }               
                }
                child {node {level 1}
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                    }
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                        child {node {level 3}}
                    }
                    child {node {level 2}
                        child {node {level 3}}    
                        child {node {level 3}}    
                    }
                }
                ;                           
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Audience killer list}
        
    \begin{itemize}
        \item level 1
              \begin{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3 
                        \item level 3 
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3 
                        \item level 3 
                        \item level 3 
                      \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
        \item level 1
              \begin{itemize}
                \item level 2
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
        \item level 1
              \begin{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
        
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The list syntax targets easy *typesetting* of lists. While you can twist it to grab the content, there are better syntaxes if you want a really robust solution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Interesting. Would you advise some readings I could dig in for these other syntaxes ?

Comment: well look at the syntax tikz or forest use for trees.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Options are clearer now, thank you. Either a hack of the simple lists (not that robust but easy to type) or structured lists as for trees (and it's actually what I tried to avoid [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1818)).

Comment: note your reference to the texbook is a bit confusing as you seem to be using latex lists and the plain tex definition of `\item` is unrelated to the latex definition.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's indeed a point I don't get.

Comment: it's easy enough to capture the list content but what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Among the applications, I'd like turn this list into a mindmap for instance, as described [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1818).

Comment: yes I looked at that but it wasn't immediately obvious what is the self contained source code for the mind map corresponding to the list. It seems that the hard part is getting the positioning options set up if you just have the list as a sequence of tex commands? That is if the list was presented with all the item texts fuly braced, how would you get the mind map?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Exactly ! And this hard part is actually given to the growth cycle written in the preambule. It takes care (modulo some pgfkeys) of the shape of the mindmap (circle/semi circle, any angle) or the distance to the root for level 1, level2, etc. as described [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1808).

Comment: @JeT it would be easier to answer if you showed the source of that mind map and then the only part to do would be to answer the question in the title, grabbing the `\item`  markup and generating that, reading through the answers on another site to work out what needs generating is too much, sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Understood, I amended my question that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally redefine the list commands so they expand into the tikz node tree markup. (I use xdef here, depending on the actual text content you may need `\protected@xdef` or similar)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\definecolor{myuniversity}{RGB}{36, 0, 132} 

%--------------------
% GrowCycle
% Till level 5
%--------------------
\makeatletter
\newif\ifmmap@debug
\mmap@debugfalse
\newcommand{\mmap@debug@message}[1]{\ifmmap@debug
    \typeout{#1}%
    \fi}
\def\tikz@mmap@store@aux#1#2{%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\xdef\noexpand\csname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\string\endcsname{#2}}}%
\def\tikz@mmap@get@from@aux#1#2{%
\ifcsname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\endcsname
\edef#2{\csname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\endcsname}%
\else
\edef#2{0}%
\fi
}   
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{MMapNodesAtLevel}{1}{%
\tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-\@roman{#1}}{\pgfmathresult}}
\newcount\tikzcountchildi
\newcount\tikzcountchildii
\newcount\tikzcountchildiii
\newcount\tikzcountchildiv
\newcount\tikzcountchildv
\newcount\tikzcountchildvi
\tikzcountchildi=0
\tikzcountchildii=0
\tikzcountchildiii=0
\tikzcountchildiv=0
\tikzcountchildv=0
\tikzcountchildvi=0
\tikzset{Julien growth/.style={%
    growth function=\tikz@grow@Julien,
    mmap/initialize counts,
    /tikz/execute at end scope={%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-i}{\the\tikzcountchildi}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-ii}{\the\tikzcountchildii}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-iii}{\the\tikzcountchildiii}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-iv}{\the\tikzcountchildiv}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-v}{\the\tikzcountchildv}%
       \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-vi}{\the\tikzcountchildvi}%
    }},
    mmap/.cd,
    initialize counts/.code={\global\tikzcountchildi=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildii=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildiii=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildiv=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildv=0%
        \global\tikzcountchildvi=0%
    }
}


\def\tikz@grow@Julien{%
    \pgftransformreset% 
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall xshift}}%
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall yshift}}}%
    \ifcase\tikztreelevel 
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildi}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildi by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildii}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildii by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildiii}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildiii by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildiv}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildiv by1\relax%
    \or
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/offset angle}%
            +\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}*\tikzcountchildv}%
        \global\advance\tikzcountchildv by1\relax%
    \fi
    \mmap@debug@message{level=\the\tikztreelevel,%
        \the\tikzcountchildi,\the\tikzcountchildii,\the\tikzcountchildiii,
        rotation=\pgfutil@tempb,sibling angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sibling angle}}%
    \pgftransformrotate{\pgfutil@tempb}%
    \pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
}
\makeatother
                
                
\tikzset{%
mmap/.cd,
    name/.initial=undef,
    overall rotation/.initial   = 0,
    overall xshift/.initial     = 0pt,
    overall yshift/.initial     = 0pt,
    sign/.initial               = 1,                
    child weight/.initial       = 0.5,      
    rotation/.initial           = 0.5,
    shape angle/.initial        = 180,      
    distance to 1/.initial      = 4.5cm,        
    distance to 2/.initial      = 7.5cm,        
    distance to 3/.initial      = 10cm,     
    distance to 4/.initial      = 12cm,     
    distance to 5/.initial      = 14cm,     
    offset level 3/.initial     = 0,        
/tikz/.cd,
    offset angle/.initial=0, 
    Xshift/.style={xshift=#1,mmap/overall xshift=#1},
    Yshift/.style={yshift=#1,mmap/overall yshift=#1},
%    branch color/.style={
%        concept color=#1!80,
%        ball color=#1!50,
%        every child/.append style={concept color=#1!50},
%    },
}


%----------------------------------------------
% Style of the mindmap
%----------------------------------------------
\tikzset{mymmstyle/.style 2 args={
    text width=1.5cm,
    align=flush center,
    mindmap,
    Julien growth,
    mmap/overall rotation=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/rotation},
    mmap/sign   = 1,
    mmap/name   = semicirc, %<- you need unique names if you want to use several mindmaps
    every node/.style={
        concept,
        circular drop shadow, 
        execute at begin node=\hskip0pt,
        text=#2,
    },  
    node font=\sffamily,
    nodes={concept},
    concept color=#1,
    root concept/.append style={
        ball color=#1, 
        line width=1.5ex,
        text=#2,
        font=\LARGE\bfseries\scshape,
        minimum size=3.25cm, 
        text width=3.25cm
    },                   
    level 1/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 1},%
        font=\large,%
        minimum size=2.5cm,%
        text width=2.0cm, 
        fill= #1!70,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(1)-1),1)}
    },
    level 2/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 2},%
        font=\normalsize,%
        minimum size=1.5cm,%
        text width=1.5cm, 
        fill= #1!50,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(2)-1),1)}
    },
    level 3/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 3},
        font=\normalsize,
        minimum size=1.5cm,
        text width=1.5cm, 
        fill= #1!30,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(3)-1),1)},
        offset angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/offset level 3}
    },
    level 4/.style={%
        level distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/distance to 4},
        font=\normalsize,
        minimum size=1cm,
        text width=1cm, 
        fill= #1!30,
        sibling angle/.evaluated={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/shape angle}/max((MMapNodesAtLevel(4)-1),1)},
        offset angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/offset level 4}
    },
}
}


%\newcommand{\MyMindMap}[2][mymmstyle={blue}{white}]{
%\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]    
%%  \begin{scope}[#1]   
%%  \input{#2}
%{#2}
%%  \end{scope}
%\end{tikzpicture}
%}

\begingroup
\def\begin#1\item{\iffalse{\else}\fi child \iftrue{node {\else}}\fi}
\def\end#1{\iffalse{\else}\fi}
\def\item{\iffalse{{\else}}\fi  child \iftrue{\else}\fi node \iftrue{\else}\fi}
\xdef\tmp{\iftrue{\else}\fi
    \begin{itemize}
        \item level 1
              \begin{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3 
                        \item level 3 
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3 
                        \item level 3 
                        \item level 3 
                      \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
        \item level 1
              \begin{itemize}
                \item level 2
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
        \item level 1
              \begin{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
                \item level 2
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3
                        \item level 3
                      \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
}}
\endgroup


\def\tmpstart#1{\node[root concept] {Root}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Audience catching mindmap}


    
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[mymmstyle={orange}{orange!50!black}]
                \expandafter\tmpstart\tmp;
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: After the "wow !" I need now to digest your code :) Merci ! Next target for me is to wrap your great solution into an environment to be able to simply type in my flow :
```\begin{mymindmap}[mymmstyle={orange}{orange!50!black}]{Root}
    The list
\end{mymindmap}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple quick opening notes:

1. There is no legitimate *TeXbook* pdf to take a screenshot from, I really hope you have a legitimate paper copy of the book that you've paid for.¹
2. *The TeXbook* describes **plain TeX** which is different in many significant ways from **LaTeX**, one of which is the handling of lists, so it's not a good place to try to understand how `itemize` works to begin with.

Getting back to our problem here, we would need to redefine `\item` and the `itemize` environment to capture their contents. A top-level `itemize` would be different from a nested `itemize`.

Thinking off the top of my head:

- `\item` will

  - if this is not the first `\item`, we close off a capture of tokens and save it somewhere (say a macro `\@itemdata(ZZ)-XX` where `XX` is the number of the item and `ZZ` is the prefix which would be the `(ZZ)-XX` string for the enclosing item of the list or an empty string otherwise. Since we'd have to use `\csname`…`\endcsname` in creating this name, there's no reason not to just use arabic numbers and a dash to separate.
  - For all `\item`s in the list, we begin a token capture.
- `\end{itemize}` will close off the capture of tokens for the last list in the itemize. It should also store the count of items in its list, say in `\@itemcount(ZZ)`
- `\begin{itemize}` inside a list will set the prefix `ZZ` to the current `(ZZ)-XX` string and then begin a new list.

The coding itself, given the above should not be too hard, but I should be in bed now, so I won't attempt it at the moment.

---

1. Trying to run an unmodified `texbook.tex` through TeX will give you a warning that you're not supposed to do that. It's trivial to circumvent, but you shouldn't do that. Bonus anecdote: back in the early 90s, Tom Reid, the author of TeXrox, a DVI driver for Xerox 87xx/97xx laser printers, made a small edit to the copy of `texbook.tex` on the Texas A&M IBM mainframe to replace `cmr10` with `cmr1O`. A document printed using the latter font flagged the job and the offending user found himself with a bill for the full retail price of *The TeXbook* (the proceeds were sent to DEK), and had an unbound copy of *The TeXbook* with no index (if I recall correctly, the index was not in older copies of `texbook.tex`).

Comment: Thank you for the notes on the TeXbook. I replaced the image with a quoted reference in text. Eager to see your MWE :)